# Escape single quote when using Pandas with tuple for IN statement

Tags: python, postgresql, pandas

I am trying to use the IN statement with psycopg2. I am passing a tuple, however one of my items is a string that contains a single quote (ex: l'Enfant Plaza).

When converting it into a tuple, Python automatically adds double quotes (ex: ('Union Station', "l'Enfant Plaza", 'Dupont Cir'))

Therefore, when I execute the SQL query, I am getting an error:

```
dataframe = pd.read_sql("""SELECT * FROM trips
                                WHERE originlocation IN {}
                            """.format(origin_locations_tuple), connection)


ERROR: column "l'Enfant Plaza" does not exist
```

Comment: You are not using Psycopg directly. Do not build the query string yourself. Check how to pass query parameters using Pandas.

Answer (score 3):

Clodoaldo's advice put me on the right track. Using the pandas query parameters solved it. The working version looks like this:

```
sql = """SELECT * FROM final_trips_prod
                            WHERE (dateoftrip + origintime)
                                BETWEEN (TIMESTAMP %(datetime_selected)s - INTERVAL '3 HOURS')
                                AND (TIMESTAMP %(datetime_selected)s + INTERVAL '3 HOUR')
                            AND originlocation IN %(origin_locations)s
                            AND destinationlocation IN %(destination_locations)s
    """
dataframe = pd.read_sql_query(sql = sql,
                              con = connection,
                              params = {
                                  'datetime_selected': datetime_selected,
                                  'origin_locations': origin_locations,
                                  'destination_locations': destination_locations})
```